# Resulting precision of operations on Oracle NUMBER

Tags: oracle, precision, arbitrary-precision

What is the precision of the value resulting in an operator on 2 Oracle default/as-given NUMBER columns (where NUMBER has no (p,s) set))? Like if I:

```
create table foo(field1 NUMBER, field2 NUMBER);

insert into foo (field1, field2) values (1.1, 3);

select field1/field2 as f1df2 from foo;
```

Will `f1df2` be 0.3666666666666...7?

Answer (score 0):

> Will `f1df2` be 0.3666666666666...7?

Yes.

Numbers inserted into `NUMBER` columns that were created without setting `p,s` are stored ['as given'](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832). The resulting precision of an operation on these columns appear to be the precision and scale of highest precision and scale column:

```
create table test_number(f1 number, f2 number, f3 integer);
-- remember integer in Oracle is NUMBER(38)

insert into test_number (f1, f2, f3) values (1.1, 3, 4);

select f1/f2 as f1df2, f2/f3 as f2df3 from test_number
```

Results in:

```
F1DF2                                     |F2DF3
------------------------------------------|-----
0.3666666666666666666666666666666666666667|0.75
```

**Note that this is true even if `f1` was re-defined to be `NUMBER(p, 1)`!** It appears that defining `(p,s)` for a `NUMBER` field only restricts precision of the data being entered into the field.

Now, what happens if we mixed the arbitrary precision type with a float? Well, according to Oracle [Numeric Precedence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i156865) rules:

> - If any of the operands is BINARY_DOUBLE, then Oracle attempts to convert all the operands implicitly to BINARY_DOUBLE before performing the operation.
> - If none of the operands is BINARY_DOUBLE but any of the operands is  BINARY_FLOAT, then Oracle attempts to convert all the operands implicitly to BINARY_FLOAT before performing the operation.
> - Otherwise, Oracle attempts to convert all the operands to NUMBER before performing the operation